# Display MySQL Results into HTML Table with URL

Tags: php, mysql

The code below isn't working as intended.  I was wanting 3 columns with the first column being a site name, the second column being the category, and the third being the URL for RSS (haven't gotten to that part yet).  The data is in the database but when I view the result of the statements below, the site name results link to the current web page I am on.  I would greatly appreciate any assistance with getting each column of data to display on the page correctly.  Thank you

```
<?php

$query="SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_numrows($result);

echo "
<table border='1'>
<th>Site Name:</th>
<th>Category:</th>
<th>RSS:</th>";

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$siteName =mysql_result($result,$i,"siteName");
$category =mysql_result($result,$i,"category");
$category =mysql_result($result,$i,"url");
$rss =mysql_result($result,$i,"rss");

echo "
<tr>
<td><a href='$url'>$siteName</a></td>
<td>$category</td>
<td>$rss</td>
</tr>";
$i++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<table>";
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>$line ["siteName"]</td>";
    echo "<td>$line ["category"]</td>";
    echo "<td>$line ["url"]</td>";
    echo "<td>$line ["rss"]</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

skip $num, mysql_resuls ( the way how you do it ) open row TR in headers ( I skipped it ) and close table

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Joanna, I really appreciate it.  If you were to have used my existing code could you show me how you would have done it so I could learn (still very much a rookie etc).  Thanks again!

Comment: I strongly suggest to rewrite your loops to more effective way (just fallow manuals like http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php) and do not waste time to fix wheel reinvention :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "
<table border='1'>
<th>Site Name:</th>
<th>Category:</th>
<th>RSS:</th>";
```

Should be:

```
echo "
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Site Name:</th>
<th>Category:</th>
<th>RSS:</th>
</tr>";
```

To start with.

Comment: Or dispense with the hideous multiline echo and having to use single quotes in the HTML and replace that with a nice HEREDOC

Answer (score 0):

Or just use some tool like SDTable.com or jqGrid and let them do all job for you =)

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question asked. It should have been a comment to the original question  instead.